# Python programming with names and values in files

Tags: python

Hi I've got a question about my code:

```
def mata_in_resultat():
    with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:

        data = [[int(value) for value in line.strip().split()] for line in f ]
        f.seek(0)


        i = int(input("Add your result to column! \n"))
        j = int(input("Add your result to row! \n"))

        data[i][j] += 1 # Assign to the index of the column and row


        for line in data:
            f.write(' '.join(map(str, line)) + "\n")


        f.truncate()
        print(data)
```

The code does that it opens the file.txt that contains for example:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Choosing a specific value in a column and a row for example `i=0 j=0` manipulates the file and saves the new information (deletes the old info)

```
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

**My question is; how do I link a name to each row (horizontal lines) in the file, for example:**

*1. having the name in the file, being able to continue to change specific values as before:*

```
Pear 1 0 0 0
Apple 0 0 0 0
```

*2. or somehow linking each row (horizontal line) to a name in a separate file*

When I do this to my current file the message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Apple'
```

shows up!

Comment: You naming row or column,check your question 1?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I am naming the horizontal lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the quickest hack to add that to your existing code is to change this line:

```
data = [[line.strip().split()[0]] + [int(value) for value in line.strip().split()[1:]] for line in f ]
```

and also:

```
data[i][j + 1] += 1 # Assign to the index of the column and row
```

---

what I'm doing there is only `int`ing the numbers in the row, and then moving the input one column to the right to account for the extra column that you've added.

### On the other hand

you might be interested in using something like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do this.

you could do something like

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None)

data.columns = ['name', '1', '2', '3', '4']

j = int(input("Add your result to column! \n"))
i = int(input("Add your result to row! \n"))

data.loc[i, j] = data.loc[i, j] + 1

# this maybe should be
# data.ix[i, j] = data.ix[i, j] + 1
# i don't really use integer indexing so i'm not 100%

data.to_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', index=None)
```

Comment: does this mean that the extra column containing the names are linked to each row? I am only asking cause I will later on sort the order of the rows.

Comment: I think you want to do this differently - i'm adding more info to the answer about `pandas`. but yes, this does currently keep the names with the rows.

Comment: It tells me `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Only tells me that there is `no module named pandas`

Comment: you will need to install `pandas` (not panda, or Panda)

Comment: the reason you get `list out of range` is that you have your inputs backwards and I followed you, so i accidentally added to row rather than column, I think I've fixed it.

Comment: oh this is for a course, I don't think its allowed to use external softwares :/

Comment: I would check. Python programming is mostly about using external packages. :)